# How do I get credentials to WCF using Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider

Tags: wcf

I have an existing WCF webservice using TransportWithMessageCredential works fine

I need to access it from new CORE apps as I upgrade my system piece by piece.

MS CORE Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider does not support message credentials

I have created an endpoint using TransportCredentialOnly. 
Unprotected webservice methods work fine but webservice does not receive the credentials for PrincipalPermission authorisation passed as:

Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUserName";
  Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword!";

It may be because I set transport clientCredentialType="None" but "Basic" setting throws an error.